# Can we use JavascriptExecutor - When my element is identified uniquely by xpath. I wish to type text using javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working with the frame, and wish to enter text on the frame.

Locator I have is created by XPath.
can we use JavaScript executor, In this case to enter text?

Comment: Just switch to the frame.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  In general, JavascriptExecutor accept element as argument not locator. so no matter you use xpath or css selector to locate the element. As Lambatman mentiond, if there is frame/iFrame in page, you need to switch to that frame, then you can operate element inside it. you can finde such selenium API:  driver.switch_to_frame(framehandle), for different language the API is different.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to your frame, locate your element then you can either use sendkeys if it is a text field or do it with JavaScriptExecutor as follow;

c#:

```
IWebElement name = driver.FindElement(By.Id("elementId"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteAsyncScript("arguments[0].value='Changed Text'", name);
```

java:

```
WebElement name=driver.findElement(By.id("elementId"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeAsyncScript("arguments[0].value='Changed Text'",name);
```

and you can switch to frame with;

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("frameName");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do it:

- Using argument

  ```
  driver.get("http://google.co.in/");
  JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  WebElement searchInput=driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
  js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='car';", searchInput);
  ```
- Using getElementById()

  ```
  driver.get("http://www.netmeds.com/");   
  js.executeScript("document.getElementById('header1_keyword').value='CAR';");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript executor for any action, it is not conected to locator or element.